# Handle errors in http test requests

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am using jest to test  my code:

```js
export const getReq = async () => {
  let data = '';
  await fetch(
    'https://api.github.com/repos/javascript-tutorial/en.javascript.info/commits',
  )
    .then((response) => {
      let status = null;
      if (response.status === 200) {
        status = response.status;
      } else {
        status = 'error';
      }
      if (status === 200) {
        alert('success');
      } else {
        data = '';
        alert('Error');
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((commits) => {
      data = commits.map(({ sha }: any) => sha)[0];
    });
  return data;
};
```

And now i want to test the situation when in my alert should appear:  `alert('Error');` and `data = '';`. So, for this i created this test:

```js
test('Asynchronous return values error', async() => {
  global.alert = jest.fn();
  global.fetch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce({
    json: () =>
        Promise.reject(new Error('my error')),
    status: 401,
  });

  const result = await getReq();

  expect(global.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Error');
  expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      'https://api.github.com/repos/javascript-tutorial/en.javascript.info/commits',
  );
  expect(result).toEqual('');
});
```

But when i run the test i get: `Error: my error` and my test does not work
What could be the issue and how to test the things that i described above?

Comment: You don't currently have *any* handling for promise rejection, in the code or the test. You're mixing `async`/`await` and `.then` within the same function - pick one, use it consistently and read up how to handle rejection. Also I'm not sure if that's a correct representation of what happens when the API responds 401, and do you really want your code to return a promise resolving to `''`?

Comment: Also look at https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async

Comment: @jonrsharpe,  i just want to test if the code is not 200 to output alert(Error),  and according to my code if the code is not 200 the data should be an empty string.  Could you help?